# Can I remove a (valid, saved) form from a Django formset, re-presenting the now-smaller formset with problems back to the user?

Tags: django, django-forms

I presented the user with a formset with all forms attached to existing instances. The user edited the forms, leaving at least 1 valid, but others with problems. I'd like to .save() the valid one, remove it from the formset, then present the remaining formset back to the user (retaining their input and the accumulated validation messages.

My code is roughly:

```
def formset_view(request): 
    successes = []

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = MyModelFormSet(request.POST)
        for form in formset[:]:
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                successes.append(form.instance)
                formset.forms.remove(form)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            pass
    else:
        formset = MyModelFormSet(...)

    # ... render response w/ successes to display and formset
```

But, after doing the formset.forms.remove(), there's an IndexError ("list index out of range") on the formset.is_valid() line.

Is there a formset-friendly way to cherry-pick the valid forms for saving, while re-presenting only the rest?

Comment: You're going to have to determine which forms were valid (say form #3 and #5 are valid), modify the management data (`form-TOTAL_FORMS`) to reflect the new form count, then modify all fields to reflect their new indexes with #3 and #5 removed (`form-4-field-here` is now `form-3-field-here`). I'm wondering if the easiest way to do this is to just iterate through the invalid forms and creating the properly indexed POST data manually.

Comment: Indeed, looking a bit at the source suggested it would be a messy operation at best... lots of assumed/stored lengths. But this seems like a natural use-case: present many items needing work, if the user succeeds on some but not all reduce the set on each submit without discarding input-in-progress. Perhaps an enhancement request...